# Подключить свой класс

Tags: wordpress

Глупый наверное вопрос, но где подключить свой класс в wordpress что бы я мог его использовать функции в теме и плагине? Пытался подключить с плагина в тему через require_once но не работает почему то, а копировать класс в плагин и тему совсем глупо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку плагины инициализируются раньше темы, то объявлять такой класс надо в плагине. В теме его можно просто использовать. Так, например, многие темы работают с классами WooCommerce.

Чтобы при отключении плагина сайт не упал при обращении к классу из темы, в теме надо проверять его наличие с помощью `class_exists()`